# Чем отличается создание переменной "int?" от "int"? в C#

Tags: c#

Чем отличается создание переменной в стиле `int? a;` или ещё `string? str = Empty.String;`?

Answer (score 1):

`int? value;` символизирует `Nullable<int> value;` Что означающее, что структура типа, которая не является ссылкой, может указывать на (пусто) `null`;

`string` - ссылочный тип данных. Он и так может указывать на null. Для него бессмысленно указывать nullable. Хоть и можно.
Достаточно написать:

```
#pragma warning disable nullable
```

Comment: А отличается то чем?

Comment: Не бессмысленно.

Comment: Тем, что структура, не может быть null. Благодаря этому, может.

Comment: @Blackmeser что не бессмыслено? Ты наверно на уровне hello world застрял. Тип строковый - это массив типа символьный. А любой массив (в ЯП C#) может иметь null. То есть, указатель будет указывать на не что. А те кто строку помещают в Nullable<T> - это люди, которые любят ездить на квадратных колесах.

Comment: @MRXIT ``string?`` это НЕ ``Nullable<string>``, как и любой другой ``Reference?`` И прежде чем кидаться оскорблениями и ТЫкать, может стоило для начала ознакомиться с матчастью!?

Comment: @Blackmeser вот ты серьёзно???? Не Nullable? А я что сейчас пытаюсь донести? Он без Nullable уже может иметь null по умолчанию. Поэтому этот обобщенный класс не нужен типу string. Тип string - ссылочный!!!! АУ, он ссылочный. Ему не нужен Nullable. Я могу написать: string message = null; - это правильно.

Comment: @MRXIT короче, учи матчасть, ``?`` для ``string`` нужен. Как и для ``byte[]?``.

Comment: @Blackmeser смысле учить матчасть? Ты просто спонтанна так пишешь, потому что ты не прав не в чем. Сдай тип bool, или long или decimal. Ты по умолчанию к этим типам не когда в жизни не присвоишь значение null. Это Value Type. Она выделяется (ты ущербный) в стеке. А не в динамической памяти. А любой массив или тип string выделяется через new в динамической памяти. И она может иметь null. Эти типы не нуждаются в этом классе. Это как указатель на указатель в с++. Зачем??? Это тебе не с++ чтобы писать int** value...

Comment: @MRXIT Я про ``Reference?`` (это не ``Nullable<Reference>``), а не про всё остальное, просто до этого нужно дорасти, чтобы понять, где это нужно, и где без этого никак.